# Twitter bot stops after first post after being deployed on Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, twitter, bots

I made a simple little twitter bot that quote tweets itself once an hour, and for some reason it stops working after it makes the first tweet. These are the heroku logs below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqQFZ.jpg

Looks like the "state" just switches from "up" to "down," but it doesn't say why. I know my code works because I tested it a lot locally and it worked just fine, so I'm not sure what's happening here. Here's the main code for the bot:

```
import tweepy
import time
import sys
import os

#--------------------Twitter credentials---------------------#
from os import environ

#Fill in on Heroku dashboard
CONSUMER_KEY = environ['CONSUMER_KEY']
CONSUMER_SECRET = environ['CONSUMER_SECRET']
ACCESS_KEY = environ['ACCESS_KEY']
ACCESS_SECRET = environ['ACCESS_SECRET']

#---------------------Connect to Twitter---------------------#
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_KEY, ACCESS_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

#----------------------Generate Tweets-----------------------#
lastTweet = None
num = 1
def createTweet():
    global lastTweet
    global num

    #Get most recent tweet ID
    for status in api.user_timeline('RecursionBot', count = 1):
        tweetID = status.id

    #Attach ID to template URL
    blankURL = 'https://twitter.com/RecursionBot/status/'
    mostRecentTweet = "{}{}".format(blankURL, tweetID)

    #Generate new tweet
    tweet = "Level: {} \n {}".format(num, mostRecentTweet)
    num += 1

    return tweet

#------------------------Post Timer-------------------------#
interval = 60 * 60
while True:
    print("Generating tweet...")
    newTweet = createTweet()
    api.update_status(newTweet)
    time.sleep(interval)
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Apps on Heroku that do not do anything within an hour will be idled to save compute resource. You can [read more about this](https://blog.heroku.com/app_sleeping_on_heroku) on the Heroku site.

> When Do Apps Sleep?
>
> When an app on Heroku has only one web dyno and that dyno doesn't
>   receive any traffic in 1 hour, the dyno goes to sleep.

Comment: I read up a bit on this. If an app doesn't receive traffic after 30 minutes it shuts down. The thing is I have a friend running a very similar script and he isn't having any issues. The procfiles are identical. Not sure what's going on.